# Invoke a COM Method from a dll

Tags: dll, com

The question is this: i've been inspecting kaspersky gadget and found out it uses a COM object as i can see declared in the gadget's main html file, so i looked in the registry by the CLSID and got to the "gadget.dll" located in the kaspersky instalation folder.
Mi interest is to invoke specific kaspersky's app tab just the same way they do. Examining the .js files on the gadget's folder i could see the syntax of the method i would need to use which is "OpenWindow(WindowID)" and the WindowID's are also specified in another file.
I've been trying this from a simple VisualBasic Script:

```
Set kavCOM = WScript.CreateObject("KISGadgetCOM.COMClass.1")
kavCOM.OpenWindow(1)
```

that should invoke the Main Window, also tried a AutoHotKey Script:

```
^!k::
{
kavCOM := ComObjCreate("{ED6E691B-E662-4aae-AECC-705C9B014C75}")
kavCOM.OpenWindow(1)
}
```

they both result in the error: 80004004 (Operation aborted) at the line with "kavCOM.OpenWindow(1)

what's wrong?

Comment: Hey, just want to know if i can not invoke the "OpenWindow" method that way, the syntax is (as seen on VBSEdit): "Sub OpenWindow(ByVal dwWindow As WindowID)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was the Object instantiation delay, i solved it by adding
    WScript.Sleep 1000
just before calling the "OpenWindow" method.

My final(finer) solution so that it doesn't wait more than needed:

```
Dim kavCOM, Cnt
Cnt = 0
Set kavCOM = CreateObject("KISGadgetCOM.COMClass.1")
On Error Resume Next
Do
 Cnt = Cnt + 1
 kavCOM.OpenWindow(1)
 If Err = 0 Then 
  Exit Do
 Else
  Err.Clear
 End If
 WScript.Sleep 10
Loop
On Error Goto 0
MsgBox "It took " & 10*Cnt & " miliseconds."
Set kavCOM = Nothing
```